# ScalaTest: where Checkers are used and assertions are used

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am going through the coursera functional programming and have an assignment where the scalatest is written using FunSuite and Checkers.

This test framework is new to me but I have some basic idea of using assertion, as I have developed pigunit for an user defined function using assert.

As google didn't give me clear usage of Checkers and how it is different from assert, could anyone clarify where Checkers can be used and why not assert be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you know, an assertion is a way of testing that a certain condition holds. These are pretty simple in ScalaTest, as you only need to use `assert`. For example:

```
assert(List(1, 2, 3).length == 3)
```

"Checkers," or, as they are more often called, **properties**, are a bit different. They are a way to assert that a condition holds *for all possible inputs* instead of for a single case. For example, here is a property that tests that a list always has a nonnegative length:

```
check((ls: List[Int]) => ls.length >= 0)
```

At this point, ScalaTest defers to [ScalaCheck](https://www.scalacheck.org) to do the heavy lifting. ScalaCheck generates random values for `ls` in an effort to find one that fails the test. This concept is called **property-based testing**. You can read more about how to use it in ScalaTest [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/property_based_testing).